# Visibility Analysis crashes QGIS 3.22

Tags: qgis, analysis, visibility

Every time I try to perform any of the tools from the Visibility Analysis plugin QGIS crashes. I'm using the latest LTR, QGIS 3.22.4. When I click any of the options (Viewshed, Visibility Network, etc) it simply crashes and I get the following message:

Crash ID: 6fc4632ef032f182772abbbbcfe1d5362b5f7615

I've tried installing plugin from zip, rebooting, reinstalling QGIS, installing elder versions, etc... but nothing works. I'm not seeing this issue to anybody else, what makes me worry even more. Please, let me know if someone has any clue.

Comment: Is it happening with any data? Did you try a new profile?

Comment: Hi bugmenot123, I cannot even try... It crashes before opening the tool. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Maybe make a bugreport on the plugins issue site. Does it work on other/older QGIS versions?

Comment: Are you sure, that your RAM memory is enough?